# How can I use a local mdf file on another computer?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a program in Visual Studio, it is written using asp.net and C#.

My database is local (e.g i use the database of Visual Studio). When I want to run my project on another computer, it doesn't work.

I must convert it from local mode to user mode

How can I fix it?

Comment: Actually I tried to attach it to a system that has sql server express but it doesn't work , I think because my project connection string is described locally and I must change the mode of database from system to user but I can't do it

Comment: But I don't want to change connection string for every pc that I work with it

Comment: Yes i do this, but until the db is local I must change connection string for every pc, actually I want to convert my local db to user based db

Comment: And with which connection string?

Comment: How can i convert windows authentication to sql server authentication?

Comment: No I didn't mean it! I want to change my database from windows authentication mode to sql server authentication

Comment: You haven't posted any error messages yet. Start with that. Never write 'it doesn't work'. Always post an exact error message

Comment: The answer to a lot of your questions is in your connection string. You need to find that and post that as well.

Comment: why not use SQL Server Management Studio Express or any other version. with a script u can work your app anywhere.